# Displaying and updating score in Android (OpenGL ES 2)

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I'm using a `FrameLayout` where I have a `GLSurfaceView` at the bottom and a few `View`s on top of it. One of those `View`s is a `TextView` that displays the current score.

Here's how I'm updating the score `TextView` based on what happens in my game loop: whenever an event happens that increases the score, I call `activity.runOnUiThread(updater)`, where `activity` is the activity that has the above `FrameLayout` (my main game activity) and `updater` is just a `Runnable` that increments the score. From my understanding, using `runOnUiThread()` from the OpenGL thread is standard practice - otherwise you'll get an exception, I can't remember its name.

The problem is that there's a very noticeable lag between the event and the score update. For example the character gets a coin, but the coin count is not updated quickly. I tried summing all the score events from my game loop and calling `runOnUiThread()` only once per loop, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference - the lag is still noticeable.

How can I improve my design to avoid this lag?

Comment: Render your text using OpenGL instead of using a TextView. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android/10751193) on SO. The same goes for other views. To get the best performance, render everything to the `GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: @free3dom Thanks for your comment. The lack of support for rendering texts is the reason I chose using TextViews, but it seems that there aren't many advantages in this approach. :( I'll probably have to go back to OpenGL.

Comment: The lack of native text rendering in OpenGL is very annoying, but once you have a system in place it is really quite painless :) I wrote a [tutorial](http://fractiousg.blogspot.com/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html) on doing this using OpenGL ES 1.0 and it was ported to OpenGL ES 2.0 [here](http://primalpond.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/rendering-text-in-opengl-2-0-es-on-android/).

Comment: @free3dom Ha, I didn't realize it was your tutorial <I actually first read it a while ago>. Nice job! Will look at using that soon. :)